# results not showing during indexing elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am performing elastic search full indexing using Bulk request. I have an issue during the indexing the results are coming as empty. As I am deleting the index during the full index, How I can handle this situation.

I have done the these steps:

- delete index
- Create index
- Create Mapping
- bulk request

Index properties and Mapping:

```
{
"products": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "assemblyrequired": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "australianmade": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "australiasellable": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "avgRating": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "category": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "categorylevel1": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "categorylevel2": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "categorylevel3": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "categoryname": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "categoryname_old": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "clearance": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "commercialuse": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "customisable": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "depth": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "freedelivery": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "genericcolourcode": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "height": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "hideprice": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "listprice": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "materialcode": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "moneybackguarantee": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "newrelease": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "numberOfRating": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "online": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "outdooruse": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "predictivecategorydata": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "pricematchguarantee": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "productcode": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "productid": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "productimageurl": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "productname": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "producttypecode": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "promotedprice": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "sale": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "saleprice": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "sellable": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "sellercode": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "shortdescription": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "sku": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "sortweight": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "state": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "stylecode": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "warrantycode": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "weight": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "width": {
                "type": "float"
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": "1",
            "provided_name": "products",
            "max_result_window": "500000",
            "creation_date": "1595814303422",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "uuid": "sGJxwr73Rkyu7-JekWFYsw",
            "version": {
                "created": "7060199"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have around 75k documents.

Thanks,
Sree.

Comment: Please show your index settings and mappings that you get by running `GET your-index-name`

Comment: are you using Spring Data Elatsicsearch? If so, which version of it, and which version of Elasticsearch? How do you create the mapping without creating the index?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch sorry after deleting the index I am creating the mapping and then mapping.

Comment: @Val added settings and mappings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the full index to be available during the reindex, your only option is to not delete the original index until after the indexing is done. In that case, I would probably work with [aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html). For example, let's assume `products-2020.07.28` was your current index, you would then create a new index for today and change the alias as soon as the indexing is done.

- Create Index

  ```
  PUT /products-2020.07.28
  {
    "settings": {
      ... your settings ...
    },
    "mappings": {
      ... your mappings ...
    }
  }
  ```
- Bulk Index Request
- Change Alias to new Index

  ```
  POST /_aliases
  {
    "actions" : [
      { "remove" : { "index" : "products-2020.07.27", "alias" : "products" } },
      { "add" : { "index" : "products-2020.07.28", "alias" : "products" } }
    ]
  }
  ```
- Delete old Index

  ```
  DELETE /products-2020.07.27
  ```

Any requests can then go directly to the alias, instead of the index.

```
GET /products/_search
```

That way you can reindex without the user noticing anything.

Comment: How Search request will know the Alias Name? Do I need to change all the requests with the new Alias Name?

Comment: Yes, you would change your search requests to use the alias name instead of the index name.

Comment: Sorry,I am confused can you please give more inputs..Every time it is hard to change the alias in the code.lets say if I ran full indexing daily once.Do you want to change the alias name in the code as well?